# Как удалить крайние блоки, которые не вмещаются в контейнер?

Tags: css, вёрстка

Есть девять блоков выстроенных в ряд (`display: inline-block`).

Каким образом можно скрывать крайние элементы (слева), если они не помещаются в контейнер? (оставшиеся блоки должны прижиматься к левой стороне).

Скрывать нужно именно целиком, поэтому `overflow-x: hidden` не подойдёт.

Comment: "удалять" css не умеет, так же как и определять вмещаются блоки в линию или нет.

Comment: Я имел ввиду "скрывать", в прочем Вы исказили суть вопроса кардинально. А скрывать не вмещающиеся блоки можно справа, если контейнеру задать фиксированную высоту и (overflow-y: hidden). Но, к сожалению, такой фокус не пройдёт, если блоки нужно удалять один за одним слева.

Comment: @Максим дайте пример, поможем

Comment: Есть хлебные крошки, выводятся они слева направо. При уменьшении ширины экрана нужно крайний левый элемент скрывать (все элементы должны быть в одну строку и вмещаться в контейнер).